# Remove over all line in plot

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock to display some sensor data. As the Highstock update 1.3.8 came out today I upgraded and found that there is a new line displayed by default on the plot:

[image]

This new line seems to connect the very first and very last data point.
Is there a way to disable this new unwanted feature? I could not find something mentioned in the changelog or in the API documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data should be sorted via x, ascending.

Comment: It is, and this line did not occur before the update (used Highstock 1.3.7). Also the line is only visible when I fully zoom out. As soon as I zoom in it displays without this line

Comment: Could you reproduce it on jsFiddle.net as live demo ?

Comment: Ah, never mind. Adding a ORDER BY in the database query that loads the data fixed the problem, seems like not all of the data was sorted correctly.

Comment: It makes sense, great ;)